# SwiftUI Not Applying Custom Font to Tabbed View

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, xcode11

I'm trying to display FontAwesome Icons in my tabbed view but swift isn't having it.

Here is my code:

```
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            Text(" \u{f466} First View")
                .tabItem {


                          Text("\u{f466} First Vw")

                }
                .tag(0)
            Text("Second View")
                .tabItem {
                       Text("\u{f466} First View")

                }
                .tag(1)
        }.font(Font.custom("Font Awesome 5 Free", size:18))
```

It's utilizing the custom font in the first Text (main labels) but not in the tabs.

How do I fix this?

Thanks[image: ![enter image description here]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9tiJg.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**FontAwesome** unfortunately does not work with `tabItem`. As for the reason why, so far I couldn't find it. As you can see, in simple `Text`, it works!

The good news is, there's a work around for that.

Using **FontAwesome.swift**

```
pod 'FontAwesome.swift'
```

Github: https://github.com/thii/FontAwesome.swift

```
var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $selection){
            Text("First View")
                .tabItem {
                    Image(uiImage: UIImage.fontAwesomeIcon(name: .coffee, style: .solid, textColor: .black, size: CGSize(width: 30, height: 30)))
                    Text("First Vw")
            }
            .tag(0)
            Text("\u{f075} Second View")
                .font(Font.custom("FontAwesome5Free-Solid", size:18))
                .tabItem {
                    Text("\u{f075} First View")
            }
            .tag(1)
        }.font(Font.custom("FontAwesome5Free-Solid", size:18))
    }
```

We make an `Image` object for our `tabItem`, but using `UIImage`.
And that `UIImage` will be coming from FontAwesome.

[image]

Comment: You are amazing! Thanks Glenn!

Comment: Maybe you can answer one more question. I'm trying to run the preview of this but I'm getting this error:

<unknown>:0: error: cannot load underlying module for 'FontAwesome_swift'

The project builds fine though unless I build the preview.

Comment: Interesting. For that, if I don't answer that right, consider posting a new question. Try restarting your Xcode, and re-build. :) It should be fine.

Answer (score 0):

Quick Update to Glenn's answer. When you add the Pod make sure you add it to your tests so you can run see the UI demos.

Do that with:

```
platform :ios, '13.1'
    target "AppName" do
        pod 'FontAwesome.swift'
    target 'AppNameTests' do
        inherit! :complete
    end 
    target 'AppNameUITests' do
        inherit! :complete
     end
end
```